# this.load.setBaseURL in javascript

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I am trying to learn javascript and phaserjs and in an index.html I find a line that says:
this.load.setBaseURL('http://labs.phaser.io');
Someone knows what is the function of setBaseURL ?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Loader.LoaderPlugin.html#setBaseURL__anchor) says that,

```
If you want to append a URL before the path of any asset you can set this here.

Useful if allowing the asset base url to be configured outside of the game code.

Once a base URL is set it will affect every file loaded by the Loader from that point on. It does not change any file already being loaded. To reset it, call this method with no arguments.
```

So, it will work to change the base path for the assets/files that will be loaded after the declaration.